# why does the CLEAR button seem to disable my listbox label output?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, listbox

When I run my program with a listbox everything works after selecting the items and pressing enter, but when I press the clear button and I select the items again and press enter nothing happens. I've tried the following for the clear button and they clear my label text and the selected listbox but I can no longer produce another output when I try pressing enter button again after selecting the items.

```
 public partial class frmLabSix : Form
{
    public string strCakes;
    public int cakeCost;


    public frmLabSix()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void lstCakes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        for (int index = 0; index < lstCakes.SelectedItems.Count; index++)
        {
            strCakes += Environment.NewLine + lstCakes.SelectedItems[index].ToString();

            if (lstCakes.SelectedIndices[index] == 0) cakeCost += 18;
            if (lstCakes.SelectedIndices[index] == 1) cakeCost += 25;
            if (lstCakes.SelectedIndices[index] == 2) cakeCost += 40;
            if (lstCakes.SelectedIndices[index] == 3) cakeCost += 30;
        }

    }

    private void lblOrdered_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double tax = 1.13;
        lblOrdered.Text = "You have ordered: " + strCakes + '\n' + "Total Cost: " + (tax * cakeCost).ToString("C");
        lblOrdered.Visible = true;
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstCakes.SelectedItems.Clear();
        lblOrdered.Visible = false;
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me why this is?

Comment: @spender, Sorry, Windows Forms Application

Comment: Clicking the check mark beside an answer marks a question as Solved, you do not need to, nor should you, change its title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code hides your label.

```
lblOrdered.Visible = false;
```

You make your label invisible on clear button click. Do you reset its visibility after? 
I don't know, what happens in other part of your code, but it should probably be like this:

```
// if the label is not visible, the next line won't make it visible implicitly
lblOrdered.Text = ... 
//you should set label's visibility explicitly
if (!lblOrdered.Visible)
    lblOrdered.Visible = true;
```

Setting label's text doesn't make it visible. If you hide it with your own code, you should make label visible explicitly as well.

Comment: NO, that doesn't make sense either. The code you posted must not have any side effect, and I do doubt that this code raises the problem.

Comment: @Kiviuq `lblOrdered.Visible = false;` you make your label invisible on clear button click. Do you reset its visibility after? Say, `lblOrdered.Visible = true;`...Setting label's text doesn't make it visible. If you hide it with your own code, you should make visible explicitly as well.

Comment: @Kiviuq Nevertheless, add `strCakes = string.Empty;' and 'cakeCost = 0;' to your `btnClear_Click`.

Comment: @Kiviuq You use `+=` in `lstCakes_SelectedIndexChanged` and never clear `strCakes` and `cakeCost`.

Comment: That is it! adding strCakes = string.Empy and cakeCost = 0; does it! Thank you so much for you patience and persistence. Cheers my friend. I appreciate your help a lot.